# Create a circular clippath that is always 300% height of the element ot clip and aligns left

Tags: css, clip-path

Is a duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77675438/clipping-an-element-with-a-circle-thats-always-300-height-of-the-parent) question, which was apparently too vague.

I want to clip elements using a clip-path in CSS, having specific requirements. I've been fiddling with it and reading MDN docs, but can't figure out how to do it, and if it can even be done.

The clip-path should be a perfect circle (so I was thinking about the `circle` function), of which the left side aligns with the left side of the element to clip. The circle should obtain its diameter by getting the height of the element to clip, and multiple that by 3 (so the circle should be 300% of the height of the element to clip).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Where the red bit is my content, the part of the element I want to keep/show. The element could have different widths and heights, the clip-path should adapt to that.

**Clarification edit**
I don't know how large the element to clip is going to be. The whole point of this question is that the clip-path should adapt itself to whatever the element will be.

Comment: Hi @GuidoGoluke, could you add the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi @ChrisHappy well just something like `clip-path: circle(300% at 150%)`, I know that that is wrong, since 100% is what's needed to cover the entire element by using pythagoras. So I figured I'm stuck to the `ellipse` function, but that won't always give me a perfectly round circle, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Temani offered good idea, but `farthest-side` is not correct in this contest.

Width of box is not important, let height 1, then radius should be 1.5.
And center of the circle should be (1.5, 0.5).

```js
const boxElement = document.getElementById("box");
const height = parseFloat(boxElement.offsetHeight);
const radius = height * 1.5;
boxElement.style.clipPath = `circle(${radius}px at ${radius}px ${height / 2}px)`;
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the whole point of it is that I don't know how tall and how wide the box is going to be. Is this going to be one of those times where I'm going to need Javascript?

Comment: @GuidoGoluke, I updated my code with script.

Comment: Hm, this does seem to do a better job than @TemaniAfif, since it gets the correct radius as well

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible to get the height but getting the width is doable

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  /* place the center at 300% from the farthest side (the left one) */
  clip-path: circle(farthest-side at 300% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: You offered good idea, but `farthest-side` is not correct in this contest.

Comment: Well you assume I know how large the box will be, but I don't. It needs to be adaptive.

Comment: @GuidoGoluke it's adaptative. I am not assuming anything. I simply gave the solution based on width not height. It's 300% of the width

Comment: @TemaniAfif hey, you're right! Care to elaborate? I've been fiddling with the params, but would never have come up with this.

Comment: @GuidoGoluke it's all about the farthest-side. I place the element at 300% 50% and the circle will expand until the farthest side which is the left side since the center is place far at the right.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understand, but this does not ensure the diameter of the circle is equal to the height of the element to clip times 3 right?

Comment: @GuidoGoluke no, it's the width not the height (as I said in my answer)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Then this doesn't do what I need it to: the diameter of the circle should be 300% of the height of the element

Comment: @GuidoGoluke I know .. and I clearly said this in my answer : "Not sure if it's possible to get the height"  so I gave the solution that use the width **not** the height since there is no CSS way to get the height.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Well let's hope someone comes here looking for that then!